# Problemas con PHP y AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy creando un modal que al cambiar el option del select me cambie los valores de la consulta, pero me sale el siguiente error. Alguien me puede explicar que estoy haciendo mal por favor.

Ajax

```
$("#puestoHorario").change(function(){
        var puestoHorario = $(this).val();
        var turnoHorario = $("#turnoHorario").val();
        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'modal/modalHorarios.php',
            data: {puestoHorario: puestoHorario, turnoHorario: turnoHorario},
            method: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#tablaHorariosPuesto").html(response);
            }
            
        })
        
    })
```

PHP

```
<table id="tablaHorariosPuesto" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">Nombre</th>
                            <th>Lunes</th>
                            <th>Martes</th>
                            <th>Miercoles</th>
                            <th>Jueves</th>
                            <th>Viernes</th>
                            <th>Sabado</th>
                            <th>Domingo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['turnoHorario']) || isset($_POST['puestoHorario'])){
                            $turnoHor = $_POST['turnoHorario'];
                            $puesHora = $_POST['puestoHorario'];
                            $sqlHorTur = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE puesto='$puesHora' AND turno='$turnoHor'";
                            $queryTurHor = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlHorTur);
                            while($turHor = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTurHor)){
                                $datosTurHor .= '<tr>
                                <td>'.$turHor[1].'</td>
                                    </tr>';
                            }
                            echo $datosTurHor;
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Y este es el error   *** Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: Si correcto, era eso. Gracias

Comment: Deberías publicar como lo solucionaste

Comment: Solamente agregue el archivo php de la conexion a la BD.
include '../../../conexion/conexion.php';
En la conexion esta $mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "*****l");
Por ese motivo no encontraba los parametros de $mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Esta muy claro, `$mysqli` es `null`, no lo estas definiendo previamente.
Creo que la función `mysqli_query()` espera recibir como primer parámetro la sentencia SQL: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Tu línea:

```
$queryTurHor = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlHorTur);
```

sería:

```
$queryTurHor = mysqli_query($sqlHorTur);
```